# Making Kartik GridView to only show after search

Tags: gridview, yii2, kartik-v

So I am doing some adjustments in my gridview and one of them is to show the gridview as blank and only to show results after I search. I know it is a unusual adjustment to make but that's what I was asked to do.

I cant just comment the dataprovider because it must be set. Is it something i can do just by the view? Thanks in advance

Comment: If`Yii::$app->request->queryParams['SearchModelName']` is not empty then display gridview.

Comment: Do you want to show empty grid (to display headers and filter) or show nothing at all?

Comment: i was thinking about an empty grid that shows the result only after I search for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it. If anyone in the future wants to know

At the ProdutosSearch:

```
$query = Produtos::find();

// add conditions that should always apply here
if (!isset($_GET['ProdutosSearch'])){

$query = Produtos::find();
$query->where('1 = 2');
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
]);
return $dataProvider;
}

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
]);

$this->load($params);
```

Nothing changed at the controller

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new ProdutosSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding cheking if submited filter parametrs has values:

```
$searchModel = new Articles();      
$query = Articles::find();
$loadData = Yii::$app->request->get();
$scope = $searchModel->formName();
$isLoadedAttributes = false;
if(isset($loadData[$scope])){
    foreach($loadData[$scope] as $attributeValue){
        $isLoadedAttributes = $this->isLoadedAttributes || (bool)$attributeValue;
    }
}
if($isLoadedAttributes){
  $query->where('1 = 2');
}else{
    $searchModel->load($loadData);
}

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => query,
]);
```

Comment: I literaly couldn't understand a thing hahahaha it looks like you dont use the modelSearch or modelQuery so it got me confused

Comment: Real fragment from search model:
$loadData = ThRmGridView::getMergedFilterStateParams();
        $scope = $this->formName();
        if(isset($loadData[$scope])){
            foreach($loadData[$scope] as $attributeValue){
                $this->isLoadedAttributes = $this->isLoadedAttributes || (bool)$attributeValue;
            }
        }
        $this->load($loadData);